# Android global variable not working between Service and Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-manifest

I've been struggling for hours now, my global variable seems to work in my service but when I try access that variable from my activity it gives no results.

Global var class:

```
public class GlobalShare extends Application{
    public static GlobalShare singleton;
    public List<LocationUsageDB> processed = new ArrayList<LocationUsageDB>();


    public static GlobalShare getInstance(){
        return singleton;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        singleton = this;
    }
}
```

Relevant service code:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if(gpschanged){
                Time t = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
                t.setToNow();
                String date = t.format("%Y/%m/%d");
                mydb.insertRecord(new LocationUsageDB(foregroundTaskAppName, date, t.hour+":"+t.minute+":"+t.second, "true", "false", Double.toString(worker.getLastKnownLocationNetwork(getBaseContext()).getLatitude()), Double.toString(worker.getLastKnownLocationNetwork(getBaseContext()).getLongitude()), worker.getLastKnownLocationNetwork(getBaseContext()).getAccuracy()));
                List<LocationUsageDB> contacts = mydb.getAllRecords(); 
                Log.v("process method called", contacts.size()+"");
                Process(contacts);


    }
    public void Process(List<LocationUsageDB> contacts){
            boolean first = false;
            GlobalShare gv = (GlobalShare) getApplicationContext();

            for (LocationUsageDB cn : contacts) {
               // String log = "Id: "+cn.id+" ,Name: " + cn.AppName + " ,Date: " + cn.Date+ " ,Time: " + cn.Time+ " ,Gps: " + cn.Gps+ " ,Network: " + cn.Network + ",latitude:" + cn.Latitude + ", lonitude:" + cn.Longitude + ", accuracy:" + cn.Accuracy;
                //String name, String date(freq), String time(nothing, String gps(freq), String network(freq), float accuracy(avg)   

                if(first){
                    Log.d("processsing contacts", cn.AppName);
                    if(cn.Gps == "true"){
                        gv.processed.add(new LocationUsageDB(cn.AppName, "1", "", "1", "0", cn.Accuracy));
                    }
                    else{
                        gv.processed.add(new LocationUsageDB(cn.AppName, "1", "", "0", "1", cn.Accuracy));
                    }
                    Log.d("first", "add");
                    first = true;
                }
                else{
                    Log.d("processsing contacts", cn.AppName);
                    for (LocationUsageDB p : gv.processed) {
                        if(cn.AppName == p.AppName){
                            gv.processed.add(new LocationUsageDB(cn.AppName, "1", "", "0", "1", cn.Accuracy)); //change still, but dummy data to try get it working
                        }
                        else{
                            if(cn.Gps == "true"){
                                gv.processed.add(new LocationUsageDB(cn.AppName, "1", "", "1", "0", cn.Accuracy));
                            }
                            else{
                                gv.processed.add(new LocationUsageDB(cn.AppName, "1", "", "0", "1", cn.Accuracy));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

The log results show everything is working correct and data is added

The "problem" i think, Activity:

```
public class Statistics extends Activity {
    Timer timer= new Timer();
    DataHandler mydb;
    ListView listview;
    StatisticsAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_statistics);

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewStatistics);
        GlobalShare gv = (GlobalShare) getApplicationContext();

        adapter = new StatisticsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.customstatistics_layout, gv.processed);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

The size of this gv.processed is 0... if I used Log.v

The manifest:

```
<application
        android:name="com.example.tracksme.GlobalShare"
        android:allowBackup="true"
.....
```

And I don't have e.g

```
android:process=":MyService"
```

what caused problems for other people.

Please help me! really stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean that your service started first, then open Activity but list empty?

First, try to replace all (in both Service and Activity) `GlobalShare gv = (GlobalShare) getApplicationContext();`
by `GlobalShare gv = GlobalShare.getInstance();`

Second, check carefully again, do not start your Service in another process by remove `android:process=":MyService"`. 
The common reason is about the process.

Answer (score 0):

in the activity, where you initial your "gv" , try this instead...

```
 gv = GlogalShare.getInstance();
```